# How to convert mssql datetime to mysql datetime

Tags: mysql, sql-server, datetime

How can i convert this **Feb 23 2011  9:00AM** to this in mysql **2011-02-23 00:09:00** ? is there any built in function available in mysql?

Comment: MySQL is very well documented, and it seems you know what you're looking for: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE('Feb 23 2011 9:00AM', '%b %d %Y %l:%i%p'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick reply. is it possible to do it in PHP?

Comment: Once again, try to do some research yourself: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php

Answer (score 1):

If you have problems with convertind MSSQL Date (i got dates in integer) there is a simple solution to convert this integer to MySQL date

```
FROM_DAYS(DOC_DATE+693961)
```

693961 is a number of days from 1900-01-01.

Hope it would help someone